# default link to $USER/desktop which works in every language

Tags: filesystem

Is there any static link (and I'm sure there is, but I couldn't find it) which defaults to `$HOME/desktop` if I've changed the language.

My problem is, I'm writting a little program and want to put some files on the desktop. My system is in german and other systems may use other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple:

`xdg-user-dir DESKTOP` will print the path I need.

I can also use `DOWNLOAD, TEMPLATES, PUBLICSHARE, DOCUMENTS, MUSIC, PICTURES or VIDEOS` to get the other file locations.